Failed to compile, Module not found: Can't resolve './xxxx'
Please assist, I have a Next.js project and want to import a file from another folder into my main app. Please assist me with the correct syntax, paths etc.. I am getting the following error, see screenshot below following by the two files:

Thease are the two files below:

//src/components/AdminApp.tsx

    "use client"; // remove this line if you choose Pages Router
    import { Admin, Resource, } from "react-admin";
    import OverviewList from "./sidebar/OverviewList.tsx";
    
    const AdminApp = () => (
      <Admin>
        <Resource
          name="Overview" list={OverviewList}
        />
      </Admin>
    );

export default AdminApp;


//src/sidebar/OverviewList.tsx

import { List, Datagrid, TextField, DateField, BooleanField } from 'react-admin';
       
    export const OverviewList = () => (
        <List>
            <Datagrid>
                <TextField source="id" />
                <TextField source="title" />
                <DateField source="published_at" />
                <TextField source="category" />
                <BooleanField source="commentable" />
            </Datagrid>
        </List>
    );


You should be able to use import { OverviewList } from "./overviewlist.tsx" or else use export default OverviewList

Like Kokodoko mentioned in the comment, wrapping the OverviewList in {} brackets should do it.

import { OverviewList } from "./overviewlist.tsx"

When you import a component that's defined with 'export const' then it's assumed there may be multiple exports from that file so it needs to be deconstructed with {} brackets. If you do a single export by using 'export default' then you won't need the brackets.

The error is "module not found". It means that the compiler doesn't find the module, not the named export of the module.

@EricMORAND Thanks for your response, could this be an add-in to declare something in the .json files? ex: in dependencies etc....

Your code import "./sidebar/Overview List.tsx" from "src/components/Admin app.tsx". Which means, it imports "src/components/sidebar/OverviewList.tsx"...which does not exist. I think your code should import "../sidebar/OverviewList.tsx".

@EricMORAND Thank you, this worked, the page came back up with the Overview resource as a sidebar item, but not content coming though in the main Overview page, not sure why...i will try and figure this one out.

It seems like you're doing named export the function OverviewList.
Hence the correct way to import is
import { OverviewList } from './sidebar/OverviewList';

In case you would like to change your import style as import as a module
import OverviewList from './sidebar/OverviewList';

You need to export your function as default export
export default OverviewList;

